# Customize admin content type page design

Tags: nodes, theming, 7

i have created template file for my contenttype wallpaper but i don't know how to get form design in that page.

for example

my content type name is wallpaper, so i create template file for `page--node--add--wallpaper.tpl.php` in that page how to get title,body etc ..

(ie)node add to page design.

Thanks for advance

Answer (score 0):

See [Drupal 7 Template (Theme Hook) Suggestions](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.tpl.php/7)

You can do something like `page--node--edit.tpl.php` or `page--node--1.tpl.php`

See the available variables in [page.tpl.php](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!page.tpl.php/7)

Also you can try `hook_preprocess_page`

```
<?php
function themeName_preprocess_page(&$vars, $hook) {
  if ((arg(0) == 'node') && (arg(1) == 'add' && arg(2) == 'product')) {
    $vars['template_files'][] =  'page-node-add-type';
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your replay... But i dont have idea to get design from default contanttype to template file(Wallpaper).

Comment: @user1881412 You will get the design if you use the exact code of `page.tpl.php`

Comment: While am trying to use code of page.tpl.php, am getting below error Fatal error: Cannot redeclare seven_preprocess_page() (previously declared in C:\xampp\htdocs\wall\themes\seven\template.php:32) in C:\xampp\htdocs\wall\themes\seven\page--node--add--wallpaper.tpl.php and I wrote below code <?php
function seven_preprocess_page(&$vars, $hook) {
 if ((arg(0) == 'node') && (arg(1) == 'add' && arg(2) == 'wallpaper')) {
   $vars['template_files'][] =  'page-node-add-wallpaper';
 }
}
?>